# How to count the ways to fill a pyramid in 2d

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I am trying to count the ways to fill a 2D pyramid of base $n$.

We have a base already placed of $n$ squares and we try to fill the pyramid with squares (we can place a square only if the two below are already there). Example:

```
☐ ☐ ☐
```

We always start from a base so here $n=3$.
And we can do

```
    this      or       this
    ☐                   ☐ 
   ☐ ☐ ☐           ☐ ☐ ☐
```

and the sequence to finish filling the pyramid is forced so there are 2 possibilities.

The question is for any $n$ , what is the number of different ways to fill this pyramid (I hope this is clear). There are $\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$ blocks to place but how many ways to place them..

Comment: Do you mean a triangle?

Comment: Why did you defacd your own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** The number of ways to fill the pyramid is
$$
\frac{[n(n-1)/2]!}{1^{n-1}\cdot 3^{n-2}\cdot 5^{n-3}\cdots (2n-3)^1}
$$
Imagine numbering all of the balls in the reverse of the order they were placed. Here is an example with $n = 5$.

```
         1
       4   2
     6   8   3
   7  10   9   5
 x   x   x   x   x
```

Let us look at this triangle in a different way, by rotating the figure $45^\circ$ counterclockwise:

```
┌──┬──┬──┬──┐
│ 1│ 2│ 3│ 5│  
├──┼──┼──┼──┘
│ 4│ 8│ 9│  
├──┼──┼──┘
│ 6│10│  
├──┼──┘
│ 7│ 
└──┘
```

The result is exactly a [standard Young tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau#Tableaux) (SYT) for a triangular partition. Therefore, counting the number of ways to place the blocks is equivalent to counting  SYT's with this shape. The number of SYT's of a given shape is given by the [hook-length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula), which in this case produces the formula advertised at the beginning of this answer.